# PrimeNG p-message severity icon covers message (Angular 6 / PrimeIcons)

Tags: angular6, primeng

As shown below, the severity icon on the message box covers the actual message.  Has anyone else experienced this and/or knows of a way to resolve it (in a manner that doesn't require hacking on the source code)?  Thank you.

[image: primeng message info bug]

Versions:

```
"primeicons": "1.0.0-beta.10",
"primeng": "6.1.0",
```

---

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.2
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.2
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.9.2
```

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz please ?

Comment: @Antikhippe: wasn't aware of what that was, so yes, I will attempt to when I get a moment.